# HTML/CSS picture placement and menus

Tags: html, css

Allright, i have 3 columns and i need to put 3 pictures in a circle on top of these 3 columns and i seem to have run out of ideas how to do that.
Heres the html:

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="col1">
<img src="img"/>
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col2">
        <img src="img"/>
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col3">
        <img src="img"/>
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And heres the css:

```
.col1 {
float:left;
width:33%;
}   
.col2 {
float:right;
width:33%;
}   
.col3 {
display: inline-block;
width:33%;
}
```

Comment: I don't see where you've even attempted to put them in a circle. Also, do you mean make the images a circular shape each, or arrange them in a circular pattern?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/sixesosuza/1/ I think I nailed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i got your question well, my snipset is what you are looking for. I made some CSS changes and here you go.

```css
.col1 {
float:left;
width:30%;
margin-left:10px;
text-align: justify;
}  
.col2 {
float:left;
width:30%;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-right: 10px;
text-align: justify;
}   
.col3 {
display: inline-block;
width:30%;
margin-right:10px;
text-align: justify;
}

.col1 img{
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.col2 img{
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.col3 img{
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
    <div class="col1">
<img src="img"/>
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col2">
        <img src="img"/>
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col3">
        <img src="img"/>
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Did this help?

Comment: Just change the border-radius percentage if you want them more Circled.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your css:

```
img {
border-radius: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others. (This post was flagged by at least one user, presumably because they thought an answer without explanation should be deleted. Since I haven't the slightest idea why `border-radius` would help in any way, I have to admit to a sneaking sympathy with this position here. Please, strengthen my wavering faith that code-only answers can be marginally useful!)